# DRF get image corresponding to user

Tags: android, django-rest-framework

I am trying to capture an image in Android, send to the Django server which will process it, and give a feedback string to the android user.
So far I could:
1) Capture the image from Android end
2) Save it to Media Folder in Server
3) Pull it from Media Folder and Process
4) Send feedback to android user.

I was confused about how does the server knows which image comes from which user. Because other than that, the correct output will not be send to the android user.

To elaborate, I use an API to send my image to the server and hit a different API from the android app to fetch the processed output.

I am not storing user data from android end. What I can think of is I will store the image along with user id in a database, and this image will be processed. I have searched about it but could not find good enough resources. I would be glad if anyone gives me ideas about it.

Comment: please be more descriptive about the question. If you can send images and process images and send users processed images properly what problem are you actually facing. please be specific.

Comment: What I did so far is : one image goes to server and is stored in media folder. I take that image from media folder and i process it.But in real, there will be multiple android users who will send images continuously to server. How does my server know which image goes with which user? Also note that here is no login/sign up option for user in android app.

Comment: if the user deletes the app and then downloads it how do you know that's the same user?

Comment: Not keeping track of the user actually. Don't need to for this specific app.

Answer (score 0):

## Workflow

#### On Android (For sending the image)

- When the user downloads the app and opens it for the first time generate a random number (9 digits for safety) as an id for the user.
- when the user sends the images, send that generated id with the image.

#### On the Server

- when you get the image with the id, save the id and the image name in the database or a cached service.
- when the image is processed properly make the image/feedback requestable for the user

#### For fetching the feedback

- From Android, send the id again with the request.
- Fetch All the images/feedback associated with the id and is requestable and send it to the user

*** If you don't want to send the user all the previous feedbacks, make a boolean checker and check it when the feedback is sent to the user if you are using a database and want to store the logs. If you don't want to store the logs and using caching service delete the key-value pair.